# for loop increment in php on button click

Tags: php

I have a button when clicked its redirected to a function in which initially `$i=0` , then incremented by 1 also checked that if its less than 10 if its true then run the code. but when i again click on the button it should be incremented by 1 and now value should be 2. here is my code.

```
function test(){
    $i=0; 
    $i++;
    if($i<=10){
        sample code
    }
}
```

on button click this function is called.

Comment: When you run the function, you're setting the value of i to 0. Is that what you want to do?

If you only want i to be 0 on first run, move $i = 0; outside of the function.

Comment: You want to call this method by ajax? If you want to keep track of the count over several requests you have to save the count somewhere (e.g. in the session).

Comment: *button click* and *php* don't go well together. Php works on per-request basis. So, unless you have any kind of session handling, any new request will know nothing from the previous. So without further info of how your code incoperates the button click, we can only speculate of how to help you.

Comment: its like on submit i am redirecting to that function so on every click i want i to be increased by 1.

Answer (score 0):

Try below :-

```
var i = 1;
function test(){

  if(i<=10){
    sample code
  }
i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting $i = 0 at the start of your function, store the current value of $i in a SESSION variable and pass it on when executing the function...

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
function test() {
    if (!isset($i)) {
        $i = 0; 
    }

    $i++;
    if ($i<=10) {
        //sample code
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Everytime you call the function, $i is set to 0. For example:

Button click:

```
$i = 0;
$i++; //$i = 1;

if ($i <= 10) {
  //do something
}
```

End.

The same will happen each time, therefore you'd need to set $i outside the scope of the function.

```
class myClass {
    public $i = 0;

    public function test() {
        $this->i++;
        if($this->i <= 10){
            //sample code
        }
    }
}

$c = new myClass();

// foreach button click
$c->test();
$c->test();

echo $c->i;  // = 2
```

Comment: nice effort but as mentioned by yoshi in the comments on every request it will be 0 as it makes fresh request each time on button click.

Answer (score 0):

Script code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var i=0;
function update() {
    i++;
    if(i<=10){
        document.getElementById("mybtn").innerHTML = i;
    }
}
</script>
```

HTML code for button

```
<button onclick="update();" id="mybtn">0</button>
```